# How to add scroll around jquery's "Sortable" control

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to wrapp the jquery's [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) but it just doesn't happen I tried to wrap it by div that is smaller in heigth but it just doesn't affect it.

```
<div style="height:50px; overflow:auto;"> 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

I read a topic that there is problem with that control.

Comment: This is missing some styling, but the scrolling appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/m99mW/

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) ur code

Comment: Also works for me. Put all your code on jsfiddle and let us know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See it how it looks for me. It is weird.

http://jsfiddle.net/4B9uy/

Comment: does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You must to set `overflow:auto` in **css**..

**This might help you**
http://jsfiddle.net/yU8Ut/

Comment: Are you sure I can make it work for the exaple from right here : http://jsfiddle.net/4B9uy/